# Set Tikz picture height and width in minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

I have two tikz figures I want to place next to each other using a mini page environment. However, I noticed that something is wrong with defining the height and width of my tikz figure using `\setlength` inside the mini page, since the size of the tikz plot somehow doesn't change... Putting `\setlength` inside the `tikzpicture` environment is no option, as I want to import the tikz plot using `\input` command.

Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{document}
\newlength\pgfplotswidth


\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
{
\setlength\pgfplotswidth{.1\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\pgfplotswidth,
    height=\pgfplotswidth,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you load the tikz package? Can you please add a screenshot to your question, if the problem remains?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: The problem is in pgfplots.  Specifically, the width and height include the ticks, labels, titles etc. and are really estimates.  `scale only axis` is better to control the box, and `axis equal` will make circles etc. appear normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a minimal preamble (ideally, your MWE should include it) and tried your code in Overleaf. It works just fine for lengths larger than `0.1\textwidth`. It even works when invoking the tikz object through `\input`. If you still have the issue, please share more details about your setup (latex distribution, compiler).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\newlength\pgfplotswidth

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
{
    \setlength\pgfplotswidth{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\pgfplotswidth,
        height=\pgfplotswidth,
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
} {
    \setlength\pgfplotswidth{.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\pgfplotswidth,
        height=\pgfplotswidth,
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]